# How to instantiate a UIViewController subclass from a xib?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have a UIViewController with a UIView in interface builder. I can not for the life of me get it instantiated properly.

I am using:

`LoginViewController* myViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil]
self.window.rootViewController = myViewController;`

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is myViewController coming up nil? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the lines you have supplied, it seems that the instantiation is being done correctly. Aren't you forgetting to add the `myViewController`s view to the window? Like this:
`[self.window addSubView:myViewController.view]`

Comment: OK, I have just noticed that you set your view controller as the window's `rootViewController`, so the view should not be the problem here. Check in your NIB file if the `view` property, from the File's Owner, is connected to the main view.

Comment: If the nib's view outlet isn't set, the app should crash with an error stating such, I don't think it should run without showing anything.

Comment: This was the case.
I made a UIViewController in IB, rather than simply a UIView.
If I make the files owner of type LoginViewController and connect the view outlet to my view then this works:
`LoginViewController* myViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] self.window.rootViewController = myViewController;` regardless of whether I make  UIViewController or UIView in IB.

My question is, when would I ever need to make a UIViewController in IB, if it works with a UIView?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be one line like the way you have it, and you are forgetting one step; try:

```
LoginViewController* controller = [[[LoginViewController alloc]
    initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

It is autoreleased so that you don't have to manually release it, and that reference to the object will be released once it is no longer needed. Also, specifying the nib name is optional as long as the nib name is the same as the name of the view controller, which it appears to be in this case. So, you could really just do:

```
LoginViewController* controller = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```